# Power tripped whilst drilling a wall. Restores ok, but is it safe?

Tags: electrical, drill

Extremely stupid of me I know, but I was hanging a wall clock in the kitchen in a hurry using a corded drill plugged into a socket directly below the clock.

I was drilling slowly through the brick wall when the drill suddenly stopped working, and the RCD on the consumer unit tripped.  I also had the drill plugged in to a circuit breaker.

I'm not sure what or if any damage was done to the wiring as it is buried in the wall, however power restored ok on the CU and socket testers on the socket in question below the drill line light up green.

I'm conscious however that even if all seems ok there could still be an underlying issue which could be dangerous.

I'll have an electrician come in to inspect and test, but in the meantime for my own understanding, I'm just wondering what might have happened given the power seems to have restored ok?   Also would the electrician be able to inspect and safety test from the wires at the socket, or would they need to hack into the brick wall to inspect the cable also?

Again, I know this was majorly stupid, I just want to make sure I now go about making sure everything is safe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know you hit a wire vs. merely the drill tripping the RCD from an internal ground fault?

Comment: To test the hypothesis of @Harper , plug the drill into another socket and drill a hole or two working it hard... Or, check the hole you drilled with a light to see what is visible at the bottom of the hole... Do **NOT** poke around in the hole with a screwdriver or similar...

Comment: I don't know if they have 2-prong drills in the UK, but if that one is either 2-prong or cheap Chinese, you might even use a scrap of metal for your test article, and run a wire from the scrap to one of the consumer unit's cover screws (i.e. do it right there).

Comment: @Harper 3 pin plugs are the norm in the UK, but some drills and other devices are only fitted with 2-wire cables as they are double-insulated (the square within a square symbol). Like your suggestion of earthing the scrap test piece though, good advice.

Comment: Wouldn't the first test be to plug the drill into the exact same receptacle it was used in before, but to drill into some test object not connected to the house-- a concrete block or hard wood and see if the breaker would be tripped?